# The appropriate gap between interview and starting date

Tags: interviewing, professionalism

I am in the final year of my study, and I am expecting to finish in the next **6 months**.

I got invited for an interview to a company recently. The interview was with HR and the agenda was just about **get to know each other**.

Everything has gone well, and the HR is now asking me if I wish to proceed to the second stage of the interview now, or hold on for a while until it gets closer to my graduation.

The problem is, despite the fact that I am not in a hurry, if I don't have any offer in my hand, I will roam around and go for other interviews. But if I know the company wants me for sure then I won't continue searching and just focus on my studies.

**My question is** : Is it possible for a company to give an offer to an employee when the starting date is 4 to 5 months ahead ?

The HR has already told me that If I pass the 2nd interview, there will still be another interview so my guess is, by the time I clear all these interview steps, I should have left with another 4 months of my study.

Comment: At my current pay grade, I usually need to give 3 months notice to terminate. It's a huge risk to hand in notice without a new position lined up; and in my experience a good employer that is serious about hiring YOU, not just someone to fill a seat, will wait.

Comment: @ggdx This is not about notice periods, but about what time during your study it makes sense to start applying to jobs.

Answer (score 12):

> My question is : Is it possible for a company to give offer to an
>   employee which the starting date is 4 to 5 months ahead ?

Yes.

This happens all the time at companies that recruit from universities. They understand when students will graduate, and may make offers many months in advance of graduation.

Consider any offer carefully, weighing any other options you may have before you accept.

And if you think you still want to play the field, indicate that you aren't ready to accept yet. Ask if you can give your answer at a later date (assuming the position remains open).

Answer (score 4):

> My question is : Is it possible for a company to give offer to an employee which the starting date is 4 to 5 months ahead ?

Yes it is possible.  Make sure, however, that you have communicated your current situation to this employer.  They need to understand that you do not want to start until after your graduation.

Any good company will work to accommodate their preferred candidate if they don't have an urgent need to immediately fill the position.